# How to view log of a specific branch at a specific time in the past

Tags: git

Is there a way to see **git log** for a **specific branch** at a **specific time** in the past.

**My use case is:** 
Me and my friend work on a git project and we have 2 branches: A & B.
 - I committed a commit (1) on branch A at 7am
 - My friend committed a commit (2) on branch B at 8am
 - Then my friend merge branch B to branch A at 9am.

Now the time is 10am, I am on branch A, pulling the latest code.
How do I know that on **branch A** at **8.30am**, commit (2) is not there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: go to that branch and use git log  you should be able to see the history

Answer (score 0):

```
git branch --contains "commit(2)"
```

where "commit(2)" is a reference to the commit (SHA1 ID, e.g.). The command lists all branches where the commit is reachable from the branch head. In case of an error you know the commit is not in your repo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't think this solve my problem, the command just list all branches that the commit is on.

Comment: The question was *How do I know that on branch A at 8.30am, commit (2) is not there?* Isn't the list an answer?